# How to split webpack entries without generating new chunks with webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-splitchunks

I need to do the following with webpack 4:

```
entry: common.js, one.js, two.js

output: common.bundle.js, one.bundle.js,  two.bundle.js
```

where:

**common.js:** contains common features

**one.js:** depends on common.js

**two.js:** depends on one.js and common.js

Earlier I used webpack 3 and this was the default behaviour to generate such bundles. Now I with webpack 4 I cannot get it run

When I run it with the default webpack 4 configuration then what I get is:

**common.bundle.js** - (ok)

**one.bundle.js:** contains code of common.bundle.js (wrong, should only have reference to common.bundle.js)

**two.js:** contains code of common.bundle.js and one.bundle.js (wrong, should only have references to common.bundle.js and to one.bundle.js)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has a similar situation, I solved it with the following config:

```
"entry": {
            "main": "main.js"
        },
        "output": {
            "filename": "[name].module.js",
            "path": "./dist"
        },
        "optimization": {                
            "splitChunks": {
                "cacheGroups": {                       
                    "common": {
                        "test": /common/,
                        "name": "common",
                        "chunks": "initial",
                        "enforce": true
                    },
                    "one": {
                        "test": /one/,
                        "name": "one",
                        "chunks": "initial",
                        "enforce": true
                    },
                    "two": {
                        "test": /two/,
                        "name": "two",
                        "chunks": "initial",
                        "enforce": true
                    },                        
                }
            }
        }
```

At the end I have the following output:

**main.module.js,**

**common.module.js,**

**one.module.js**

**two.module.js**